# URL not rewritten in .htaccess when 'index.html' present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is a portion of the .htaccess rewrites:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=directions_to_business$  
RewriteRule ^$ directions? [NC,R=301,L]
```

So in essence, http://www.mybusiness.com/?pid=directions_to_business should redirect to http://www.mybusiness.com/directions.  However when this url is given: http://www.mybusiness.com/index.html?pid=directions_to_business, the URL is not redirected.

I'm using a Rails app if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code,

```
RewriteRule ^$ directions? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Only matches an empty request, i.e. the root (query strings aren't used for RewriteRule). You want this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ directions [NC,R=301,L,QSA]
```

Which will forward your query string as well (`QSA`), if you want `http://www.mybusiness.com/?pid=directions_to_business&from=...` to go to `http://www.mybusiness.com/directions?from=...`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked; but I don't want to append the query string.  I removed QSA and put the question mark back in but for some reason the URL is now being rewritten as: http://www.mybusiness.com/directions?&pid=directions_to_business

Comment: Still doesn't change the end result.

Comment: @Jake: I take it back. Apparently a trailing question mark should remove the URL.

Comment: OK, well for the rest of the URLs the rewrites are now working - but for the 1st one I tried I'm still getting an appended query string...it looks like Firefox is holding the URL in memory somewhere...I even tried restarting but that doesn't help it.  I tried the URL in IE and it's redirecting properly. So problem solved!

Comment: @Jake: Yeah, 301 is a permanent redirect, so firefox has every right to cache it. To quote [the protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2), _"This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise."_